# How to redirect default url in a flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app running a website, and it works as expected when sent to a page directly, like the url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/start_page, but when I go to just: http://127.0.0.1:5000/, I get a URL not found error. I want the url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/ to redirect to the http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/start_page page.

I tried just adding something like this to the python:

```
@bp.route('/')
def start():
    return redirect(url_for('auth.start_page'))
```

but I'm still getting the page not found error. This is how I redirect all the other URL's so I don't know what the problem is. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you're redirecting to a blueprint? is the function `start_page` defined in the blueprint? In general, it's hard to debug this without all the pertinent code posted in the question, see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes auth.start_page is defined, the function isn't being called what so ever. That function gets called on the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/, I want it to be called from just http://127.0.0.1:5000/.

Comment: Why not add @bp.route('/') to the start_page function? It is possible to have multiple routes on 1 function.